# Who made the rules about dragons in warfare?

Tags: empire-of-the-celestial-dragon

In the book *Eona*, towards the end, it is revealed that (major spoilers)

> there was no Covenant and the dragons are enslaved by the Dragoneyes and the Emperor. However, there are rules that had been followed about using the dragons; supposedly in the agreement between humans and dragons, there are rules against using their magic in a war.

If the dragons didn’t make this rule, who did? Why did they limit the Dragoneyes’ power?

Comment: Rule #1 - Don't talk about dragon warfare club